# Bash - Recursively looping through all subdirectories that contain spaces and dots

Tags: bash, recursion

I want to use something like `find` to recursively find all subdirectories and I need to do so in a `for` loop - the tasks are too complicated and long for `&`'s.

The above part is easy, but I also need it to include *spaces* and *dots* (prefixed) in the directory names - which so far I failed with every single solution I found on this SE. The names always either get split, or `find` just spits out a single string (`for` loop happens only once).

Comment: Why not use find? It is already recursive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a pure Bash `for`-loop, use this:

```
shopt -s nullglob globstar dotglob

for subdir in **/; do
    do_stuff_with "$subdir" # quote the expansion "$subdir"
done
```

- To have a recursive glob, we use `**/` with the shell option `globstar`.
- The `dotglob` option asks the shell to also glob on “hidden” files (the ones that have a leading period).
- The `nullglob` is to have the glob expand to nothing when there are no matches. (It's always a good idea to use it when looping on globs; otherwise `failglob` is a good choice when using a glob as argument to a command).

---

With GNU `find` you can also do it as follows (don't forget to use `-print0` and use `read`'s delimiter option `-d ''`, and also `-r`, and an empty `IFS`):

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' subdir; do
    do_stuff_with "$subdir" # quote the expansion "$subdir"
done < <(find . \! -name . -type d -print0)
```

The `\! -name .` predicate is to exclude the parent `./` directory.

---

Both methods are safe with respect to any funny symbols you will have in filenames **provided you quote the expansion `"$subdir"`!**

---

But I guess that the main problem you encountered with spaces is that you didn't quote your variable expansions!

> **Don't forget to *quote every single expansion* `"$subdir"`.**

---

Did I say that you should quote every single variable expansion?

Comment: I've never used `shopt`. Are those settings temporary like global variables or is it a permanent?

Comment: @areuz: If you set shell options from within an interactive shell, they will disappear as soon as the shell ends. In a script, they will only be proper to your script. In a subshell (i.e., some code enclosed within `( ... )` or code in a pipe) they are proper to the subshell.

Comment: Thank you~, that's exactly what I need!